# MySql : splitting row based on one column and manipulating other rows

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

[database table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7ldf.png)

I have a table as shown in pic with 10+ columns with number of poeple. I want the duration to be in 15 mins.i.e splitting 10:00-10:30 row to 10:00-10:15 and 10:15-10:30 and so on.
The column value should be divided by 2. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store the duration as a datetime for just the beginning of the duration. I am assuming your duration is a varchar or something now.

```
alter table your_table add duration_time datetime

update your_table set duration_time = cast(concat(date_field,'  ',left(duration_field,locate('-',duration_field))) as datetime)
```

and then always assume 15 minutes with the code that reads the table. You can then create a mysql query

```
insert into your_table
select (every field..., date_add(duration_time, interval 15 minute) as duration_time from your_table
```

will duplicate every entry and add 15 minutes.

Then when you query your data you can format the time part as time-time+15 minutes in your python code